# Flex-wrap property not responsive when parent has a set width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the example below, when I set a width for a wrapper, the parent flex container can no longer use the flex-wrap property. The top two boxes won't wrap, but the bottom ones will.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>

.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid cadetblue 5px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex: 1;

  background: mistyrose;
  border: solid goldenrod 2px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'issue' you raise is by design; you're specifying a `width` for the parent that is wide enough for your children to be wholly contained within (a `700px` container for two `300px` children). `flex-wrap` only causes elements to overflow when there's not enough space for the container to hold them. In your example, there is.

To force an overflow responsively, you could either specify a narrow `width` on the parent
(which will cause an overflow for **all** viewports):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid cadetblue 5px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex: 1;
  background: mistyrose;
  border: solid goldenrod 2px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Or use `max-width` instead
(which will only overflow on narrow viewports):

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid cadetblue 5px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 300px;
  flex: 1;
  background: mistyrose;
  border: solid goldenrod 2px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```